# Complex manifold which is algebraic away from codimension \ge 2

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, reference-request

If $X$ is a complex manifold and $Z$ is a closed subset of codimension $\ge 2$ such that $X-Z$ has an algebraic structure, then is $X$ algebraic; i.e. a scheme?  If not is $X$ an algebraic space?

To clarify: is there a global algebraic structure on $X$ that restricts to a given algebraic structure on a analytic Zariski $U$ with complement codimension $\ge 2$?

Comment: Do you want $X$ to be compact?

Comment: You can assume $X$ is compact; although I would still be curious if a statement can be made if $X$ is non compact with perhaps some "niceness" conditions on $Z$.

Comment: $X-Z$ algebraic forces enough meromorphic functions on $X$ for it to be a Moisezon space and so an algebraic space provided it is irreducible and compact.

Comment: @Ray: if $f$ is meromorphic on $X-Z$, must it be meromorphic on $X$?

Comment: What if $Z$ is a point?

Comment: Brian Conrad brought to my attention the reference "Coherent Analytic Sheaves" by Hans Grauert, Reinhold Remmert.  On pg. 185 they prove a meromorphic function on an analytic Zariski open set with complement of codim \ge 2 extends to a global meromorphic function when the global space is normal.  He also mentioned that there are smooth connected proper algebraic spaces which aren't schemes but they are schemes away from codimension 2 subsets.

Comment: "...when the global space is normal." What does normal mean for analytic spaces?

Comment: @Yuhao analytic spaces are in particular locally ringed spaces.  So normal means for every $x \in X$ the local ring of holomorphic germs $\mathcal{O}_x$ is reduced and is integrally closed in the ring of meromorphic germs at $x$.  The latter is the localization of $\mathcal{O}_x$ by its nonzero divisors.